# I have 208 V, three-phase. How do I get single-phase 208 V or 240 V?

Tags: transformer, ac

If 208 V three phase is constructed of three 120 V lines, what is the most simple and safe way to get either 208 V, single phase, or 240 V, single phase?

Comment: What's wrong with the 208 V you got between two phases? There is no "linear" combination giving you equal load and power factor on all phases.

Comment: FYI: To add to @greybeard "What's wrong with the 208 V you got between two phases?", in the US that's called "208V single phase".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

120V is from phase to neutral.  The difference between phases is 208V rather than 240V because they are 120 degrees out of phase, not 180.  You have 208V single phase between any 2 phases.  To get 240V you need a transformer

Comment: @ErricDifilippo "To get 240 V you need a transformer" A lot of US 240 V appliances will also work at 208 V so check their ratings plates before you start transformer shopping.

Answer (score 2):

Connect your load between two of the phases. To keep the system as balanced as possible, connect different loads between different pairs of phases.

Since neither connection to your load is a neutral, overcurrent protection and isolation needs to be double pole.